# How to update customer telephone if customer doesn't have in the billing address?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-address, billing-address

I want to update the customer telephone number if the customer doesn't have.
In our website we disabled the telephone mandatory in adding address field.
We recently implement a payment gateway that the telephone field is mandatory.
I want to update the customer telephone table if the customer doesn't have the telephone number in there shipping or billing address.
I tried this way.

**Created a file `update_phone.php` in the root**

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
$db   = mysql_select_db("dbname",$conn);

$sql = "SELECT ce.entity_id,ce.email, ea.attribute_code, cev.value 
    FROM customer_entity AS ce
    LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
    LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS cev ON ce.entity_id = cev.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = cev.attribute_id
    WHERE attribute_code = 'mobile'
    ORDER BY entity_id DESC LIMIT 1";

//mobile is a custom attribute it will collect during registration

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $customerId = $row['entity_id'];
    echo $customerId;//Upto this line code is working. 
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->load($customerId)->getData(); // insert customer ID
    //Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id)->getData();

    foreach ($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress() as $address)
    {
        $data = $address->toArray();
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

Up to `echo $customerId;` code is running.

My scope is **get the mobile number** and **check the billing telephone number** is available in the customer address with the customer id and **if telephone number is not available want to update with mobile number**.
please Help me in this task

Comment: did you include Mage.php '`require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app("admin");`

Comment: @AmitBera yes i included require_once 'app/Mage.php'; not umask(0); Mage::app("admin");.after adding those it is not working

Comment: @AmitBera i changed the code like Mage::app('default'); and $customer->getAddresses() instead of $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress().Now i can get the values.

Comment: You don't need all that crazy mysql hassle, Magento handles it for you when you include `app/Mage.php`

Comment: @JulienLachal can you please suggest me a way to reach this.Hope you understood my task.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting data change

**from**

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->load($customerId)->getData(); // insert customer ID
    //Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id)->getData();

    foreach ($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress() as $address)
    {
        $data = $address->toArray();
        var_dump($data);
    }
```

**to**

```
   $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->load($customerId); // insert customer ID
    //Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id)->getData();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getData());
```

If you want to *`update primary billing address telephone from mobile number(custom attribute)`*  IF ***telephone field is empty***

then using *customer address model*`(Mage::getModel('customer/address'))` update this address telephone.

```
$address=Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getEntityId());
$address->setTelephone($customer->getMobile());
$address->save();
```

Comment: Thank you,Your comment helped me.but i am not complete my task.

Comment: are  you want save getPrimaryBillingAddress address telephone to customer attribute mobile field.Am i right?

Comment: I want to Update the mobile number(custom attribute) value to primary billing address telephone IF telephone field is empty for the same customer.

Answer (score 1):

I simplify this task than i post the question.For future readers to get some idea i'll post the new way how i did here.Thanks **Amith** for helping me.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('max_execution_time',1200);
ini_set('max_input_time',1200);

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$start = microtime(true);

for($a=1;$a<=57;$a++) {
$customers = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
       ->addFieldToFilter(array(
            array('attribute'=>'mobile','neq'=>'')        
        ))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('default_billing')
       ->setPageSize(2000)
       ->setCurPage($a);
foreach($customers as $customer) {

  $customer_mobile = $customer->getData('mobile');
  $customer->getAddresses();
  if(count($customer->getAddresses())!=0){
     $telephone_number =  $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();

  echo "customer_mobile: ".$customer_mobile."<br />";
  echo "telephone_number: ".$telephone_number."<br />";


  if($telephone_number=='') { 

        $address=Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getEntityId());
        $address->setTelephone($customer_mobile);
        $address->save();
        echo "Customer(".$customer->getId().") who has this #".$customer_mobile." # MObile number doesent have telephone number Updated SUccessfully</br>";
        $updated_nos++;

    } else{ 

        echo "Customer(".$customer->getId().") who has this #".$customer_mobile." # MObile number HAVE telephone number</br>";

    }
}//if customer address available only update the customer telephone number
}
}

$time_taken = microtime(true) - $start;
echo " Customers Telephone Number update in ".$time_taken." Seconds";
?>
```